# Error while running behat on laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, behat

1st Try:---
When i run behat with feature set as

```
Feature: Authentication
Checking Application Authentication Functionality.

@javascript
Scenario: Admin Redirect Page
    Given I am on "/admin/dashboard"
    Then I should be on "/admin/login"

Scenario: Admin Login Failure
    When I go to "/admin/login"
    And I fill in "email" with "testaccount@gmail.com"
    And I fill in "password" with "wrongpassword"
    And I press "Login"
    Then I should see "Login Failure"
```

The first scenario works but the second one fails, response :-

```
Scenario: Admin Redirect Page        # app/tests/behat/features/auth.feature:5
    Given I am on "/admin/dashboard"   # FeatureContext::visit()
    Then I should be on "/admin/login" # FeatureContext::assertPageAddress()

  Scenario: Admin Login Failure                                 # app/tests/behat/features/auth.feature:9
    When I go to "/admin/login"                               # FeatureContext::visit()
      Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel] is not instantiable. (Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException)
```

2nd Try:---
I tried removing 1st scenario to test if my feature was broken and behat ran successfully.

```
Scenario: Admin Login Failure                                 # app/tests/behat/features/auth.feature:9
    When I go to "/admin/login"                                 # FeatureContext::visit()
    And I fill in "email" with "testaccount@gmail.com" # FeatureContext::fillField()
    And I fill in "password" with "wrongpassword"               # FeatureContext::fillField()
    And I press "Login"                                         # FeatureContext::pressButton()
    Then I should see "Login Failure"                           # FeatureContext::assertPageContainsText()

1 scenario (1 passed)
5 steps (5 passed)
0m3.70s (23.80Mb)
```

I am not sure why it is failing when i implement 2 scenario.

3rd Try:---

```
Feature: Authentication
    Checking Application Authentication Functionality.

    @javascript
    Scenario: Admin Redirect Page
        Given I am on "/admin/dashboard"
        Then I should be on "/admin/login"

    Scenario: Admin Redirect Page
        Given I am on "/admin/dashboard"
        Then I should be on "/admin/login"

    Scenario: Admin Redirect Page
        Given I am on "/admin/dashboard"
        Then I should be on "/admin/login"
```

result:-

```
Feature: Authentication
  Checking Application Authentication Functionality.

  @javascript
  Scenario: Admin Redirect Page        # app/tests/behat/features/auth.feature:5
    Given I am on "/admin/dashboard"   # FeatureContext::visit()
    Then I should be on "/admin/login" # FeatureContext::assertPageAddress()

  Scenario: Admin Redirect Page        # app/tests/behat/features/auth.feature:9
    Given I am on "/admin/dashboard"   # FeatureContext::visit()
      Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel] is not instantiable. (Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException)
    Then I should be on "/admin/login" # FeatureContext::assertPageAddress()

  Scenario: Admin Redirect Page        # app/tests/behat/features/auth.feature:13
    Given I am on "/admin/dashboard"   # FeatureContext::visit()
      Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel] is not instantiable. (Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException)
    Then I should be on "/admin/login" # FeatureContext::assertPageAddress()

--- Failed scenarios:

    app/tests/behat/features/auth.feature:9
    app/tests/behat/features/auth.feature:13

3 scenarios (1 passed, 2 failed)
6 steps (2 passed, 2 failed, 2 skipped)
0m2.87s (24.19Mb)
```

Comment: I have laravel 5.1.23
And behat required packages
"behat/gherkin": "^4.3",
        "behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "^1.2",
        "behat/mink-browserkit-driver": "^1.2",
"laracasts/integrated": "^0.15.6",
"behat/behat": "^3.0",
        "behat/mink": "^1.6",
        "behat/mink-extension": "^2.0",
        "laracasts/behat-laravel-extension": "^1.0",

Comment: i wastrying to learn using laracast.

Comment: on your second scenario are you meaning to go to google.com?

Comment: oops i copied wrong test output. fixed it. It shows error on 2nd scenerio no matter which page i navigate to0.

Comment: Also note if i run 2nd scenario on its own (just by itself) it works. even if switch the order, it still fails at 2nd scenario. I cant figure out what i am doing wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out, you need to add these 2 for all scenarios. If anyone have same issue, this may of be any help.

```
@javascript @mink:selenium_session
```

by default my config was to run on cmd line by behat.yml  had this

```
sessions:
        default_session:
          laravel: ~
        goutte_session:
          goutte: ~
        selenium_session:
          selenium2:
            wd_host: http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
```

so adding @javascript runs test on browser and by specifying mink session to use selenium gives you access to all javascript functionality of your app.

Comment: Also note the error was because 2nd scenario was running on command line